# Convert Windows keyStore to a jks file

Tags: java, certificate

Hello is the a way to convert windows key store into a jks file ?
KeyStore ks1 = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
KeyStore ks1 = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-Root");
Need help on the question.

Comment: You are aware that keys from those Windows stores may be configured to not be exportable?

Comment: I'am not aware of that so it's not possible for us to retrieve windows key store keys. cause every time i try to get the keys i get NPException. When trying to do key.encode()

Comment: You can usually not retrieve all the keys there. Some which are configured as exportable on the other hand should work.

Comment: Can you add your code? When you say you get a NPE, we'd need to see the code that causes it.